# Can I change the color of the whitespace markers in the TeXstudio editor?

Tags: texstudio, syntax-highlighting, white-space

I'm using a couple custom settings for syntax highlighting in the TeXstudio editor, but I'm running into a problem, and I'm not sure whether this is down to me not finding the correct settings and options, or whether this is simply not possible.

When configuring TeXstudio, with advanced options enabled, it is possible to select "Show Whitespace" in "Adv. Editor". space bar whitespace will now show up as a little gray center dot.

However, there is no setting to change the color of that dot. In "Syntax Highlighting", I tried changing the colors for the identifiers "background", "text", and "normal", each of foreground, background and "line color", to no avail.

I can't figure out how to change the color of these markers, but it would be quite nice to me, if I could to that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That color is currently hard-coded. You cannot change it.

Comment: Thanks, I guess "accepting" this is the way to go then. I'll keep this one maintained, should this ever change.

Comment: I've added this as open issue: https://github.com/texstudio-org/texstudio/issues/306